# What is the function of the (.), or in other words, what does the period do?

Tags: java

New to java programming. Can't seem to find what the period means when searching around...as in System.out.println() or when combining a Class with an instance variable, but CreditCard.balance may be an example. I came up with the following code partly by accident and partly by reason. Nonetheless, what is the (.)'s purpose.

```
public class CreditCard {
    // data members
    private static Person owner;
    private static Money balance;
    private static Money creditLimit;

    public CreditCard(Person newCardHolder, Money creditLimit) {

        CreditCard.owner = newCardHolder;
        CreditCard.balance = new Money(0);
        CreditCard.creditLimit = new Money(creditLimit);
    }

    public Money getBalance() {
        Money balance = new Money(0.00);
        return balance;
    }

    public Money getCreditLimit() {
        Money creditLimit = new Money(1000.00);
        return creditLimit;
    }

    public String getPersonals() {
        return owner.toString();
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner.toString();
    }

    public void charge(Money amount) {
        Money value = new Money(balance.add(amount));
        value = balance;
        if (value.compareTo(creditLimit) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Exceeds credit limit");
        } else {
            balance = value;
            System.out.println("Charge: " + amount);
        }
    }

    public void payment(Money amount) {

        Money value = new Money(balance.subtract(amount));

    }
}
```

The output for the record here is 
Diane Christie, 237J Harvey Hall, Menomonie, WI 54751
Balance: $0.00
Credit Limit: $1000.00

Attempting to charge $200.00
Charge: $200.00
Balance: $0.00

Attempting to charge $10.02
Charge: $10.02
Balance: $0.00

Attempting to pay $25.00
Balance: $0.00

Attempting to charge $990.00
Charge: $990.00
Balance: $0.00

if anyone wouldn't mind hinting at what I have done wrong in my execution, I'd appreciate that. My first question is the most crucial, however. Thank you to those who take the time to respond with their input.

Comment: Java's dot operator is really borrowed from the earlier C/C++ syntax which existed at the time, so you may read about dereferencing in C++ to also get a better understanding of what dot is doing.

Comment: The CreditCardDemo is the driver I am using, which applies the concept of aggregation. Something that slipped my mind, which I think I should have mentioned.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

Comment: ah ha! I was searching "period in java" or " what is (.) in java " with no success. Instead it is termed the dot operator. thank you

Comment: Probably OT, but using *static* fields means that all instances of CreditCard share the same `owner` (and the other fields)

Answer (score 0):

Period indicates the namespace. It means that the method/variable after the period is belonging to the object before the period. It is not necessarily a function.

“Creditcard.balance” just tells compiler to access “balance” of neither global variable, nor any other object, but “Creditcard”.

As for your second question, I think it is a bit confusing.